# Why am I getting variable name as output instead of its value?

Tags: python

I have a list of `Order` objects. Each object has the following properties `user_id, product_id, quantity` . 
I am using the below code to loop through the list and get the values of the properties of each object.

```
for order in Orders:
   print(order.user_id)
```

This prints the expected output. However, I need to use the `user_id` from each `order` to get the properties of a `User` object from a list of `User` objects. For this I have to convert the `order.user_id` to an integer to use it like `users[order.user_id].first_name` but when I cast `order.user_id` to an `int` , I get an error :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user_id'
```

So , when I use `print(order.user_id)`, I get the value but when I use `print(int(order.user_id))` I get `"user_id"` as output which can not be converted to an `int`. What am I doing wrong?

I have the following classes:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, user_id, first_name, last_name, email, gender):
        self.id = user_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self.gender = gender


class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, product_id, description, stock, cost):
        self.id = product_id
        self.description = description
        self.stock = stock
        self.cost = cost


class Order(object):
    def __init__(self, product_id, user_id, quantity):
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.quantity = quantity
```

This is how  I am populating the lists:

```
users = []
products = []
orders = []

"""read all the products"""

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT* FROM products')
product_rows = cur.fetchall()
for product in product_rows:
    products.append(make_product(product[0], product[1], product[2], product[3]))

"""read all the users"""

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT* FROM users')
user_rows = cur.fetchall()
for user in user_rows:
    users.append(make_user(user[0], user[1], user[2], user[3], user[4]))

"""read all the orders"""

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT* FROM orders')
order_rows = cur.fetchall()
for order in order_rows:
    orders.append(make_order(order[0], order[1], order[2]))
```

The 'make' methods:

```
def make_user(id, first_name, last_name, email, gender):
    user = User(id, first_name, last_name, email, gender)
    return user


def make_product(id, description, stock, cost):
    product = Product(id, description, stock, cost)
    return product


def make_order(product_id, user_id, quantity):
    order = Order(product_id, user_id, quantity)
    return order
```

Output when I use:

```
    for order in orders:
        string = order.user_id
        print(string)
```

I get as output:

```
80
10
25
88
48
41
93
```

When I use
    for order in orders:
        string = order.user_id
        print(int(string))

I get this output:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user_id'
```

What I am actually trying to do:

```
for order in orders:
    user_id = int(order.user_id)
    first_name = users[user_id].first_name
    last_name = users[user_id].last_name
    product_id = int(order.product_id)
    product_description = products[product_id].description
    order_quantity = order.quantity
    unit_price = products[product_id].cost
    total_price = unit_price * order_quantity

    line = user_id + "," + first_name + "," + last_name + "," + product_id + "," + \
    product_description + "," + order_quantity + "," + unit_price + "," + str(total_price)
```

I apologize if this is a very basic question.

Comment: Can you share with us the definition of the `Order` class as well as some as the output when you run `print(order.user_id)` and a sample of the data stored in `users` please?

Comment: @PabloTrinidad I've edited my question. Added more details.

Comment: Is the output above all of the values or just an example, are you 100% sure that `user_ids` are all numeric? You might want to try to catch the exception and print the string in specific, just to confirm the `ValueError`.